# How to set nested hash in ruby dynamically?

Tags: ruby, hash, nested

Lets say I have a nested hash:

```
h = { 'one' =>
        {'two' =>
            {'three' => 'a'}
        }
     }
```

I can change it like this:

```
h['one']['two']['three'] = 'b'
```

How can I change the nested value with a variable as a key?

Let's say I have the following variable:

```
key = "one.two.three"
```

To access it dynamically, I use the following:

```
key.split('.').inject(h,:[])
```

But of course setting it like this does not work:

```
key.split('.').inject(h,:[]) = 'b' # fails
```

So how can I set the value of a nested hash dynamically?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

`Hash#[]=` is a single method. You cannot do `Hash#[]` all the way to the last key and do `=` to it. Rather, leave out the last key and do `Hash#[]=` individually on it.

```
*key, last = key.split(".")
key.inject(h, :fetch)[last] = "b"
```

Answer (score 0):

Building on [sawa](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14294789/6126165)'s answer, in modern Ruby with `Hash#dig`, this becomes even simpler:

```rb
    
*key, last = key.split(".")
    
h.dig(key)[last] = "b"
```